# Android Google maps Spatial Coordinates: From GCJ-02

Tags: android, google-maps, geospatial, spatial

I am provided a LatLng that belongs to Spatial Reference GCJ-02. 
Of course it does not show up properly in google maps, since i beleive, correct me if i am wrong, google maps uses WGS-84.

Does the google map service v2 for android provide a way to display or transform GCJ-02 ?

Is my only option using geo tool? I do not want to bring in such huge library for just spatial transformation.

Thanks for all your help,
Kev

Answer (score 2):

Around the time the question was asked, the only way to convert between GCJ-02 and WGS-84 was to use an interpolation method with coordinates based on regression from a [data set of Google China and satellite imagery coordinates](http://wuyongzheng.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/china-map-deviation-as-a-regression-problem/). There is an Objective-C library on GitHub at https://github.com/maxime/ChinaMapDeviation.

However, since the question was asked, the GCJ-02 encryption code was leaked and can be found in many places online, the most popular being [the EvilTransform repo](https://github.com/googollee/eviltransform).

Further reading:

- [What causes the GPS shift in China?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/what-causes-the-gps-offset-shift-in-china)
- [Restrictions on geographic data in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static LatLng wgs_gcj_encrypts(double wgLat, double wgLon) {
    LatLng point;
    if (outOfChina(wgLat, wgLon)) {
        Log.e("Baidu", "outOfChina");

        point = new LatLng(wgLat,wgLon);
        return point;
    }
    double dLat = transformLat(wgLon - 105.0, wgLat - 35.0);
    double dLon = transformLon(wgLon - 105.0, wgLat - 35.0);
    double radLat = wgLat / 180.0 * pi;
    double magic = Math.sin(radLat);
    magic = 1 - ee * magic * magic;
    double sqrtMagic = Math.sqrt(magic);
    dLat = (dLat * 180.0) / ((a * (1 - ee)) / (magic * sqrtMagic) * pi);
    dLon = (dLon * 180.0) / (a / sqrtMagic * Math.cos(radLat) * pi);
    double lat = wgLat + dLat;
    double lon = wgLon + dLon;
    point = new LatLng(lat,lon);
    return point;
}


private static boolean outOfChina(double lat, double lon) {
    if (lon < 72.004 || lon > 137.8347)
        return true;
    if (lat < 0.8293 || lat > 55.8271)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static double transformLat(double x, double y) {
    double ret = -100.0 + 2.0 * x + 3.0 * y + 0.2 * y * y + 0.1 * x * y + 0.2 * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x));
    ret += (20.0 * Math.sin(6.0 * x * pi) + 20.0 * Math.sin(2.0 * x * pi)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    ret += (20.0 * Math.sin(y * pi) + 40.0 * Math.sin(y / 3.0 * pi)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    ret += (160.0 * Math.sin(y / 12.0 * pi) + 320 * Math.sin(y * pi / 30.0)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    return ret;
}

public static double transformLon(double x, double y) {
    double ret = 300.0 + x + 2.0 * y + 0.1 * x * x + 0.1 * x * y + 0.1 * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x));
    ret += (20.0 * Math.sin(6.0 * x * pi) + 20.0 * Math.sin(2.0 * x * pi)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    ret += (20.0 * Math.sin(x * pi) + 40.0 * Math.sin(x / 3.0 * pi)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    ret += (150.0 * Math.sin(x / 12.0 * pi) + 300.0 * Math.sin(x / 30.0 * pi)) * 2.0 / 3.0;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: what are pi, ee and a? Found it:  final static double pi = 3.14159265358979324;
    final static double a = 6378245.0;
    final static double ee = 0.00669342162296594323;

Answer (score -1):

Google maps will accept 4326 but if you really want to be correct - read this post

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-is-the-current-web-mercator-projection-code

You can use proj4 or store your data in PostGIS ( It can do the transform for you). I don't know of any library on the android client that could do this but perhaps this could the trick for you:

http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/